# Differentiating return type based on argument

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type a function that either accepts a string or string[] and returns either a bool or bool[] respectively. I've tried both using generics types and overload but both seem to throw some kind of error:

```js
// generic way
function genericWay<T extends string | string[]>(val: T): T extends string ? boolean : boolean[] {
    if (typeof val === 'string'){
        return true // Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? boolean : boolean[]'
    }
    return [true] // Type 'true[]' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? boolean : boolean[]'
}

const a1 = overloadWay('bbb')
const a2 = genericWay(['bbb'])
const a3 = genericWay(5333) // should throw error


// overload way
function overloadWay(val: string[]): boolean[]; // This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.
function overloadWay(val: string): boolean {    
    if (typeof val === 'string'){
        return true
    }
    return [true] // Type 'boolean[]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
}

const b1 = overloadWay('bbb')
const b2 = overloadWay(['bbb'])
const b3 = overloadWay(5333) // should throw error
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgOYFMLoE5ygdQEMBPAHgBVl0APGTAEwGdlGZcJVkAfFtuDgNoBdAHwAKAG6EANgC5k5AJTzKNOhCa92nAPzIARggTT0hFPMPHTEYcgDewZE+RwQyMTGIAHdAjdTpZABeEOQAclZtMMUHZzjkbHQYMGwUNjB0R2cAXyynROTU5AF09CFgXOAoJFZkQgBGYOQECRxpBEJ6ImIxMP1+6KqamDqAJiaMLFwCEjEBPoGhRSGIWsIAZgnMHDxusQBWdaPFZAB6U5YACwQwaXpkGEvsBAB3Kmxn7GBv8Gh4JGarWw7U6ewC8ki-FQwmUBiMJjMwgA3KBILBECgWm0Ol1ZuCtFDYZYESg7HE8i43B5vL5-DJgqEInwONFYvF8kkUmlsBkKbk4gUucVSuVKitavpGkFAdjQbMFvpBtVViN9ONpVjgTi9vN+oqluLVZsNUCQbieodjmcLoxrrd7o9nm8cJ8gA)

1. From the first example - it seems my return type is incorrect?
2. For the overload way, for some reason it's not picking up on type check to differentiate between the two input types.

Comment: This is a great question, but can't you accomplish the same thing even without knowing the answer if you simply have the function always take a string[] and always return a bool[]?  If you only want to pass in one string, just pass in a string[] of length 1 with your string in the first and only element.  Then you can also check for the length of the return value and convert your bool[] of length 1 to a bool if there are no other elements in the returned array?

Comment: I could, but at this point I'm also curious why this implementation doesn't work and what I'm doing wrong (for learning purposes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since another answer already provides with how to fix the warning in the generic way, which requires explicit type casting, here is how you can use function overloading to achive the same goals.

Your overload way definition is not correct. You need to specify all the overloads before the function and the implementing function should contain all the possible inputs and outputs in its signature. You may resort to `any` in the implementation, but I do not think that's advisable wherever you can avoid.

Here is the overload way

```ts
// overload way
function overloadWay(val: string[]): boolean[];
function overloadWay(val: string): boolean ;
function overloadWay(val: string| string[]): boolean | boolean[] {    
    if (typeof val === 'string'){
        return true
    }
    return [true]
}

// b1 is boolean
const b1 = overloadWay('bbb')

// b2 is boolean[]
const b2 = overloadWay(['bbb'])

// shows error
const b3 = overloadWay(5333)
```

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/YmpaXW)

Comment: That makes so much more sense - didn't realize you need to specify all overloads before the function.

Answer (score 1):

I've applied some changes to the generic way, to have a separate Generic type, and asserted the returned value type with `as`, check [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=50#code/C4TwDgpgBA5hB2AVcEA8iB8UC8VFQgA9gEATAZynOACcBLeGKAfigCMB7DgGwgEN4UAFzsuvAQG0AugG4AUHIBmAV3gBjYHQ6C48CPTUB1PiHQFiZStXqMoAHyq0GMaRgAUANz7cRiAJQiusiQ6FgA3nJQUVB0ilBuoJAccV7cONi4AOTWzpl+EdGFUDQQwMo0grTK0HyUQSihkdEAvk1RJWUVUBJVEFJQtbAIwWiYcq1yatrUAwCMOEN6BsYgbplsG3mT08ADAEwLuvp0RiZuEuubUn7b8DN8AMyHCMenqwCsD19+UAD0v1QABYcZTcUhQYCAmgcADuBBo0JoQA)

```
type genType<T> = T extends string ? boolean : boolean[];

function genericWay<T extends string | string[]>(val: T): genType<T> {
    if (typeof val === 'string'){
        return true as genType<T>
    }
    return [true] as genType<T>
}

const a1 = genericWay('bbb')
const a2 = genericWay(['bbb'])
const a3 = genericWay(5333) // should throw error
```